# Why does `boost::outcome::result` forbid the value and error types from being the same?

Tags: c++, boost, error-handling

I just found myself in a situation where I wanted to return a `boost::outcome::result<std::string,std::string>` and was surprised to find that that was explicitly forbidden that the value and error type be the same. This is especially surprising as `boost::outcome` already provides handy `success()` and `failure()` functions to make returns explicit if there is any ambiguity between the value and error types.

I'll admit that `result<string,string>` clearly isn't the *most* expressive type in the world, but this was an internal parsing/validation function that would either parse an ID string out of a large piece of JSON or return a error message describing what went wrong in detail.

It's an easy enough problem to work around. I could add a trivial wrapper struct to either the value or error type or make one an `std::optional<std::string>`, but it feels like a weird hoop to have to jump through. Why forbid using using the same type for both the value and the error?

Comment: can you quote the docs where it says that it is forbidden?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, by "explicitly forbidden", I meant that the code explicitly checks for and prevents using the same type for both value and error. At your prompting, I checked the docs and the restriction is mentioned when comparing `outcome::result` to `std::expected`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/outcome/doc/html/faq.html#how-far-away-from-the-proposed-std-expected-t-e-is-outcome-s-checked-t-e